# What permanent cards give creatures -X/-1?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm looking for cards that give my opponent's creatures at least a static -1 to toughness. (I don't really care if it also gives my creatures -1 to toughness.) The effects needs to last until removed, so it must come on a permanent of some kind. Usually I would expect a simple Scryfall search to find everything I need, but Scryfall doesn't seem to register -1/-1 as a valid input. How can I find such cards?

I know at least some cards exist:

- [Night of Souls' Betrayal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Night%20of%20Souls%27%20Betrayal)
- [Elesh Norn, Grand Cenobite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elesh%20Norn%2C%20Grand%20Cenobite)
- [Ethereal Absolution](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ethereal%20Absolution)
- [Kaervek, the Spiteful](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kaervek%2C%20the%20Spiteful)
- [Plague Engineer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Plague%20Engineer) (edge case, only gives selected creatures -1/-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gatherer supports Regex. [This search](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+%5B%22%20get%20%22%5D+%5Bm/%e2%96%ba.%e2%97%84*/-%e2%96%ba1-9%e2%97%84+/%5D+!%5B%22until%20end%20of%20turn%22%5D) produces 27 results, including all of your example, but also some false positives.**

The statement is intentionally broad so it shouldn't have false negatives, at the cost of more false positives.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/9GAuaVj.png) is a screenshot of the search terms.

The " get " excludes "gets" and "target" results.

The "m/[.]*/-[1-9]+/" term is the regex, with the leading "m/" and trailing "/" being the signal to treat the enclosed term as regex.

Exclude "until end of turn" to only get permanent P/T modifiers.

Comment: One potential pitfall of a search like that, with text inclusions and exclusions, is that they could look at different abilities. That's why you get those false positives, and in general it could also produce some negatives, though that doesn't seem to be the case here (e.g. one ability has the effect we're looking for, and a different ability has an "until end of turn" effect. In this case, it happens that there aren't any cards that would be incorrectly excluded this way.

Comment: [This Scryfall search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2F%28%3F%3C%21until.*%29%28%3F%3C%21you+control.*%29%5Cbget%5Cb.*%5B-%2B%5D%28X%7C%5Cd%2B%29%5C%2F-%28X%7C%5B1-9%5D%2B%5B0-9%5D*%29%28%3F%21.*until%29%2F) finds all of the same positive results, and removes all of the false positives, including cards that only debuff creatures their controllers control.

Comment: There's always room for more answers.